# Separar resultados por bloques

Tags: php, array

Tengo una consulta :

```
SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY title ASC
```

el cual me trae los resultados ordenados en orden alfabético.

ahora, separar con php, cada bloque los resultados según su letra inicial

**Letra A**

```
Alibaba
Andres
```

**Letra B**

```
Banana
Bruno
```

y así sucesivamente.

Código como imprime

```
while ($row = $query -> result()) {
echo $row['title'].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: ¿tiene código de cómo los imprimes por el momento? para sugerir en base a lo que has hecho

Comment: acabo de editarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código puede servirte.

La lógica es la siguiente: asumimos que el array ya está ordenado, por lo cual nos enfocamos en extraer el primer caracter de cada elemento del array, cuando lo tenemos lo almacenamos y lo revisamos en cada iteración, cuando vemos un cambio hacemos un nuevo div.

```
$tmp = "";
$band = false;
while ($row = $query -> result()) {
    // esta condicipon solo es para la primera iteración
    if (!$band):
        $tmp = substr($row['title'], 0, 1);;
        echo "<div style='border: 1px dotted gray; margin: 3px;'>";
        echo "<h1>Letra ".$tmp."</a>";
        echo "<p>";
        $band = true;
    endif;
    // extraer la primera letra de title
    $init = substr($row['title'], 0, 1);
    if ($tmp === $init):
        echo "<h3>".$row['title']."</h3>";
    else:
        $tmp = $init;
        echo "</p></div>";
        echo "<div style='border: 1px dotted gray; margin: 3px;'>";
        echo "<h1>Letra ".$init."</h1><p>";
        echo "<h3>".$row['title']."</h3>";
    endif;
}
echo "</p></div>";
```

Comment: Gracias :):))))